# Pivots of a multiplicated matrix and inverse

Tags: matrices

(My question name may be confusing. Don't mind.)

Suppose I have 2 n by n matrices A & b with full set of pivots. Now, M=A*B. Then does M is a matrix with a full set of pivots too? If so, why?
Also, the other way. Suppose M is invertible. Then does A & B necessarily have to be invertible?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I was thinking whether elimination matrices could have a full set of pivots and then the thought struck me. Well, I know anyway they have a full set of pivots. I needed to get a somewhat proof or reasoning.

Comment: Numbers are insufficient for trying. I can use variable but I don't think any outcome will come off that.

Comment: Do you know any statements about square matrices that are equivalent to being full rank?

Comment: No rows and columns can be combination of other rows and columns? (I am sorry but I didn't quite get you.) @CyclotomicField

Comment: Some other such statements would be the determinant of a matrix is non-zero, the map induced by the matrix over an $n$ dimensional space is bijective, and the reduced row echelon form of the matrix is the identity matrix. Do you have any of those results at your disposal?

Comment: Hey, my matrices are invertible. That means they ARE invertible. They have an inverse matrix, a full set of pivots, nonzero determinant etc (I haven't studies about map yet). If I had known whether M (For the 1st question) had any of those above mentioned properties, I had already know my answer @CyclotomicField

Comment: You can use that $\det AB = \det A \det B$ to answer this question both ways.

Comment: Yeah,that's right! det M=det A×det B. And thus M is invertible. Thanks.